# Fit spline with given number of knots, but not knot positions

Tags: python, scipy, spline

Given a set of 2D points, I would like to fit the optimal spline to this data with a given number of internal knots.

I have seen that we can use scipy's [LSQUnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LSQUnivariateSpline.html) to specify the *number and position* of knots, however it does not allow us to *only* specify the number of knots.

From the [UnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline) documentation, it seems implied that they have a method for fitting the spline with a given number of knots, as the documentation for the smoothing factor `s` states (emphasis mine):

> Positive smoothing factor used to choose the number of knots. **Number
>   of knots will be increased** until the smoothing condition is satisfied...

So while I could go about this in a kind of backwards way and search through smoothing factors until it yields a spline with the desired number of knots, this seems to be a rather ridiculous way to approach this from a computational efficiency standpoint.  Two extra search steps are happening just to cancel each other out and obtain a result that was already computed directly at the start.

I've searched around but haven't found a function to access this spline interpolation with a given number of knots directly.  I'm not sure if I've missed something simple, or if it's hidden deeper down somewhere and/or not available in the API.

Note: a scipy solution is not required, any python libraries or handcrafted python code is fine (I am using scipy here just because that's where all of my searches about spline interpolation in python have landed me).

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the problem?

Comment: [scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline.html#scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline)?

Comment: @Patol75 this is interpolating splines, with knots at data points

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like the UnivariateSpline [constructor](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.3/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py#L70-L191) passes off the computational work to the function [`dfitpack.curf0`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.3/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py#L185), which is [implemented in Fortran](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/src/fitpack.pyf#L251-L282).

Therefore, although the documentation indicates that the smoothing requirement is met by adjusting the number of knots, there is no way to directly access the function which fits a spline given a number of knots from the python API.

In light of this, it looks like one may need to look to another library or write the algorithm oneself, if avoiding the roundabout double search method is desired.  However, in many cases, it may be acceptable to simply run a binary search for the desired number of knots by adjusting the smoothing parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Scipy does not have smoothing splines with a fixed number of knots. You either provide your knots, or let FITPACK select it via the smoothing condition knob.